# Trigger on contact, Add record only when check box is checked on account

Tags: apex, trigger

My requirement is I can only be able to add new contact under account when Account field name check__c is true. If its not true than Error should be pop up like in active account. I tried below code but still not able to get the result. Any help please?

```
trigger check1 on Contact (after insert,after update,after delete) {
set<Id> AccIds = new set<Id>();
 if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate)
 {
     for(Contact c:Trigger.new)
     {
         if(c.AccountId!=null)
         AccIds.add(c.AccountId);
     }
 }

 if(trigger.isdelete || trigger.isupdate)
 {
     for(contact c2:Trigger.old)
     {
         if(c2.AccountId!=null)
         AccIds.add(c2.AccountId);
     }
 }

 check m = new check();
 m.checkc(AccIds);
```

Class:

```
public class check
{
    list<Account> Accounts = new list<Account>();
    list<Account> Accountstoupdate = new list<Account>();

    public void checkc(set<Id> AccIds)
    {
        Accounts=[select Id,check__c,(select Id from Contacts ) from Account where Id IN :AccIds];

         for (Account ac : Accounts) {
        if(ac.check__c == true){

        }

        else{

       ac.addError('Account in not active');


        }
    }

        update Accountstoupdate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be much simpler -- and you can take advantage of implicit DML in the before insert trigger handling

```
trigger validContact on Contact (before insert) {

  set<ID> aIdSet = new set<ID> ();
  for (Contact c: Trigger.new)   // collect parent account ids to search 
      aIdSet.add(c.AccountId);   

  // fetch Accounts as they are not implictly in trigger. save in EZ lookup map
  map<ID,Account> aIdToAccountMap = new map<ID,Account> ([select id, check__c
                                      from Account where ID IN: aIdSet]);

  for (Contact c: Trigger.new) // now, error those in trigger without parent account check true
     if (c.AccountId != null &&  // poss to have Contacts w/o accounts 
         !aIdToAccountMap.get(c.AccountId).Check__c) // inactive account per OP
        c.addError('Account is not active, contact can\'t be added');
}
```

Now, all that said, I'd invest in a trigger framework or, better yet, the Separation of Concerns pattern but those are topics beyond what you probably need here

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just need to add this trigger or any other class i have to write with this, tried this one but getting error like  Illegal assignment from Set<Id> to List<Id> at line 3 column 8

Comment: oops - my bad; fixed line 3